# exceptions.AttributeError: EchoFactory instance has no attribute 'connection'

Tags: python, twisted

First of all I would like to say that I just got started with both python and twisted so even being searching for all the errors and doubts that I have I'm sure I can still produce some silly ones.

Said that, I'm working on this client-server pair, where the client will simulate a listening loop to know if a device is connected to it and then send a message to the server with it's parameters.

First I was creating the connection, then started the loop and after that sent the file once the device was connected (you'll see that commented at the bottom of the code). Now what I'm trying to do is to create the connection when the device is connected to the client (inside the function called by LoopingCall), and here comes the problem as it throws the exception that you see in the title.

This is the client code, which is the one that is giving me troubles.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
import gri
import os

ID = '1258'
filename = 'parameters.xml'
a = 1;
reg = 0;
xreg = 0;
xdreg = 0;

#Create the radio object
radio = gri.Radio()

class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write(ID)
    def sendXML(self):
        f = open(filename,'r')
        self.transport.write(f.read())
        f.close()   

class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        self.connection = EchoClient()
        return self.connection
    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection failed."
        reactor.stop()
    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection lost."
        reactor.stop()

#listening loop
def find_usrp():
    global a
    global reg
    global xreg
    global xdreg
    global factory
    # a=0 if the device is connected, a=1 if not
    a = radio.findRadio()
    if a == 0:
        reg = 1
        if xreg == 0:
            #creating the connection once the device is connected
            factory = EchoFactory()     
            reactor.connectTCP("localhost",8000, factory)
            factory.connection.sendXML()            
            xreg = 1
            xdreg = 0
    else:
        print "Device is not connected"
        if reg == 1:
            print "Device is out"
            if xdreg == 0:
                xdreg = 1
                xreg = 0

#creating the connection before the loop
#factory = EchoFactory()    
#reactor.connectTCP("localhost",8000, factory)
LoopingCall(find_usrp).start(1, now = False)
reactor.run()
```

So that's it, I don't know why when it goes to factory.connection.sendXML() it doesn't find the connection. I've been trying different things like passing factory as a parameter to find_usrp function, changing things of place but I'm afraid I don't have enough knowledge in this language to know what is really going on... Let's see if you can help me with this so I can really learn about it. Thanks!

---

Edit:

So far what eighilaza says make sense to me, I've tried to run this line
`factory.connection.sendXML()`
some time after and it seems that it works, so maybe I'm trying to run this function before it's created. But is there any way to control this?

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. What do you mean by *it doesn't find the connection*? Is there some error message that could help for an answer?

Comment: Thank you! The error message is the one that appears in the title:"exceptions.AttributeError: EchoFactory instance has no attribute 'connection'" which is being thrown when the code reaches "factory.connection.sendXML()" inside the find_usrp function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What causes your error is that you call factory.connection before the connection is made.

In your code `reactor.connectTCP("localhost",8000, factory)` is non-blocking so you reach `factory.connection.sendXML()` before the connection is made.